# Missing files in the creation of an angular project

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

When I create an angular project there are some missing files in the creation like `app.modules.ts` and `app-routing.modules.ts`

I create the project using the command `ng new name`

this is a screen shot of all the files created:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See which *version* of the angular you are using. In the **17th** version, a project is created with standalone components by default. So you don't have those files.

Answer (score 0):

Angular ver.17 by default makes every component to standalone so there is no need for ng-module decorators anymore.

In-case you want to add/need app.module.ts then use
`ng new <app-name> --standalone false` command while creating new application.

Answer (score 0):

From ng v17, standalone is now the new default for the CLI.
When you create a new project you won't have any modules like (`app.modules.ts and app-routing.modules.ts`)

If you want module, you can use the following command to generate a project that has `app.module.ts` and `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
ng new my-app --no-standalone
```